# R - Delete/remove rows after a conditional date (multiple criteria)

Tags: r

I'm trying to remove all rows based on the date of each ID that occurs on or after the date that the ID has a "type = B".

In excel I would do this with an array search helper column to flag those for removal. Is there a cleaner way to do this in R?

**Minimal example:**

```
library(data.table)

#input
colNames<-c("id","date","type")
df2 <- data.table(c("010","010","010", "010","030","210","310"), 
                  as.Date(c("2009-08-21","2012-12-28","2014-01-01","2011-07-05","2015-04-05","2013-07-05","2012-08-01")),
                  c("A", "B","A","A", "A", "B", "B")
                  )
df2<-df2[order(df2$V1, as.Date(df2$V2, format="%y/%m/%d")),]
names(df2) <- colNames
df2

    id       date type
1: 010 2009-08-21    A
2: 010 2011-07-05    A
3: 010 2012-12-28    B
4: 010 2014-01-01    A
5: 030 2015-04-05    A
6: 210 2013-07-05    B
7: 310 2012-08-01    B
```

**Into this result:**

```
#output
    V1         V2 V3
1: 010 2009-08-21  A
2: 010 2011-07-05  A
3: 030 2015-04-05  A
```

**Thanks!**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `match` to find out the index of the first `B` and take the rows before the index with `head`; If there is no `B` found, all the rows should be returned, specifying `nomatch` to be the number of rows in the group should give what you needed (assuming the data table has been ordered by *date* column before hand):

```
df2[, head(.SD, match("B", type, nomatch = .N+1) - 1), id]

#    id       date type
#1: 010 2009-08-21    A
#2: 010 2011-07-05    A
#3: 030 2015-04-05    A
```

Or to be more efficient, you can use this alternative to avoid constructing intermediate data tables(`.SD`):

```
df2[df2[, head(.I, match("B", type, nomatch = .N+1) - 1), id]$V1]
```